# How to get record's position in a subquery in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
select 
  p.name, 
  coalesce(pfitd.data, '{}' :: json) as data 
from 
  projects p 
  left join (
    select 
      pfitd.project_id, 
      json_object_agg(
        'order-<position of entry>' , 
        json_build_object(
          'amount', pfitd.amount,
          'name', pfitd."name",
        )
      ) as data 
    from 
      project_fixed_invoice_term_data pfitd 
      left join payment_terms pt on pt.payment_term_id = pfitd.payment_term_id 
    group by 
      pfitd.project_id
  ) pfitd on pfitd.project_id = p.project_id 
where 
  p.project_id = 'pid1';
```

Is there a way to get the entry's position?

example result:

```
[
  { 
    "order-1": { "user": "Ailene , "role": "Manager" }
  },
  {
    "order-2": { "user": "Andres", "role": "Developer" }
  }
]
```

How is this possible using a query? Or do I have to do this in a client and modify the data after obtaining the query results?

Comment: I would expect a key "order" and a value"1", "2", etc. Not a new key for every value. To generate the number, you can use a window function using row_number()

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Hey Frank, sorry, I updated my query in this post.
I also tried row_number() but it does not work on aggregate functions